# Consulta em determinada string

Tags: mysql

Bom pessoal a minha dúvida é o seguinte: Eu gostaria de saber como fazer uma consulta no banco de dados de determinada string, por exemplo eu gostaria de no campo "nome", eu gostaria de fazer uma consulta pelo nome: vinicios, e gostaria que me retornasse todos os registros que contem o nome vicios independente de ser vinicios cardoso,vinicios antonio, etc.

Comment: 2 negativaram, beleza, agora só me diz o motivo de terem negativado.

Comment: Tente utilizar o operador LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select * from nome_da_tabela where nome like '%vinicius%'
```

O simbolo de % indica que pode haver qualquer coisa, ou seja, qualquer nome que contenha vinicius antes ou depois será selecionado.

Para buscar todos os nomes que começam com Vinicius por exemplo, você faria da seguinte forma:

```
 select * from nome_da_tabela where nome like 'vinicius%'
```

Comment: Obrigado :)....